# Socket.IO won't connect - /socket.io/ 404's?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a small http server with express 4, on top of which i need to add a small realtime component for which i've chosen Socket.IO. I followed their instructions and arrived to this code:

```
var https = require("https"),
fs = require("fs"),
express = require('express'),
app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('redacted.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('redacted.crt'),
  ca: [ 
    fs.readFileSync('g1.crt'),
    fs.readFileSync('g2.crt'),
    fs.readFileSync('g3.crt')
  ]
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(30572);
io.listen(30572);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('SocketIO connection received');
});

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  if (!request.secure) {
    return response.redirect(['https://', request.get('Host'), request.url].join(''));
  }

  next();
});

app.use(express.static('.'));

console.log('Listening on 30572... Ctrl + C to quit');
```

And this client code:

```
var socket = io.connect(location.origin)
```

I've noticed this message spammed to the console ever since:

```
GET http://localhost:30572/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1439410053456-0 404 (Not Found)
```

I've commented out the use block to no avail.

Is there anything i am doing wrong?

EDIT: Removing SSL made no difference.

Comment: I think you don't need the line **io.listen(30572);** also the line that set the static folder I don't think it should be dot(.) that could cause problems

Comment: express.static('.') works fine to serve the current working directory tree. Could it be messing with SocketIO? EDIT: swapped it for app.use(express.static(__dirname)); - No dice.

Comment: But serving ('.') is a security risk because you can access server.js and all the node related files, plugins, etc. I would recomend put your static files in a folder. Also the first line shouldn't be http instead of https here is a [simple example](http://socket.io/docs/)

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thank you for telling me. Also, please disregard this question. I was using the gulp server instead of my own simple server, of course it wouldn't work. :/

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this question. It was a matter of me using the gulp livereload server instead of my own server. It works now.